# use angular 2 instead of angular 4 with angular-cli

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli

How can i create angular 2 app with angular-cli instead of angular 4?

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

i tried to change the angular version but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your package.json -> dependencies array change angular version to 2.4.1 and rebuild your project.

Detail answer :-

1) Create new project using Cli.

```
ng new my-newapp
```

2) change directory to

```
cd my-newapp
```

3) update package.json -> dependencies. Change angular version to 2.4.1 and change router to 3.4.1

example:-

```
{
  "name": "my-newapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

4) reinstall all package ( **optional**:- before execute this command you can delete node-module folder)

```
npm install
```

5) launch browser

```
ng serve
```

Note :- In my system while execute ng serve i faced issue

```
ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule
```

you fix this issue by adding an empty line to the app.module.ts.

Comment: i changed @angular/core and @angular/common to 2.2.1 but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Momen  add detail answer.

Comment: i got 486 error notarget No compatible version found: @angular/animations@^2.2.1 because u changed every angular depencies to 2.2.1  but i will try your new answer and let you know