# Use Angular CLI to create a Angular 2 Project

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I am new in Angular.

I am wondering is there a way use Angular CLI to create a Angular 2 project instead of Angular 4 or 5?

I know that if I already have angular project I can manually change it to Angular 2, like this link [use angular 2 instead of angular 4 with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552009/use-angular-2-instead-of-angular-4-with-angular-cli)

But how can I create Angular 2 project at very beginning? If it needs a lower version of Angular CLI, which version? And how can I do it?

Please see my package.json file below:

```
{
  "name": "learnangular2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular2-fontawesome": "^5.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you need older version of angular.
To create angular v2 you will need a very old version of angular-cli.

You need instal order version of angular-cli

```
npm install @angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.2
```

and now you can create angular 2.0 app

```
ng new app-name
```

In this case you will use older version of angular-cli. I thing that better way is youse new angular-cli and make change in package.json to angular 2.0